# Spring reactive webclient doesn't throw ReadTimeoutException at the configured time

Tags: kotlin, spring-webflux, netty, kotlin-coroutines, reactor-netty

In our service we are using Spring Boot 2.7.16 with Kotlin. In our http calls we are using the reactive webclient wrapped with coroutines (async await). The webclient configuration for all client are as follows:

```kotlin
    @Bean
    fun xWebClient(
        builder: WebClient.Builder,
        props: WebClientProps,
    ): WebClient = builder.buildWith(props)

    private fun WebClient.Builder.buildWith(props: WebClientProps): WebClient {
        val eStrategies = ExchangeStrategies.builder()
            .codecs { configurer -> configurer.defaultCodecs().maxInMemorySize(-1) }
            .build()

        val httpClient = HttpClient.create(connectionProvider)
            .doOnConnected { connection ->
                connection.addHandlerLast(ReadTimeoutHandler(props.readTimeoutMillis, MILLISECONDS))
                connection.addHandlerLast(WriteTimeoutHandler(props.writeTimeoutMillis, MILLISECONDS))
            }
            .metrics(clientMetricsEnabled, identity())
        
        var webClient = exchangeStrategies(eStrategies)
            .clientConnector(ReactorClientHttpConnector(httpClient))
            .baseUrl(props.baseUrl)
            .build()
        
        return webClient
    }
```

Both readTimeoutMillis and writeTimeoutMillis are configured as 50 ms.

We run the http requests within async/await blocks as follows;

```kotlin
val (responseADeferred, responseBDeferred, responseCDeferred, responseDDeferred) =
            supervisorScope {
                DependenciesResponseDeferred(
                    async { serviceA.call(request) },
                    async { serviceB.call(request) },
                    async { serviceC.call(request) },
                    async { serviceD.call(request) },
                )
            }

        val fetchedData = FetchedData(
            responseA = responseADeferred.await(),
            responseB = responseBDeferred.await(),
            responseC = responseCDeferred.await(),
            responseD = responseDDeferred.await(),
        )
```

The way we make the request is this;

```kotlin
xWebClient
            .get()
            .uri(
                UriComponentsBuilder.newInstance()
                    .path("/endpoint")
                    .build().toUriString(),
            )
            .header(AUTHORIZATION, "Bearer token")
            .awaitExchange { response ->
                when (response.statusCode()) {
                    OK -> response.awaitBody()
                    else -> {
                        val message = response.awaitBodyOrNull()
                            ?: "empty. Http status code is ${response.statusCode()}"
                        throw ServiceException(message)
                    }
                }
            }
```

In my local environment I am mocking one of the downstream services by using hoverfly and adding 2 seconds delay for each call. And I am generating some traffic on the application around 40 to 80 req/s.

What I am expecting is that the webclient throws an exception when it reaches to the configured timeout value.
But it doesn't work as I expected, when I monitor the latencies I observe the ReadTimeoutException is thrown after the configured time varying between 51 to 65 ms. Here is a picture of an individual span when a [ReadTimeoutException is thrown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/clEFs.png) The span basically shows the timeline when we start the http call and it's automatically closed when the request ends.

The picture above shows the individual call span, it took 55.3ms instead of 50ms. The app waits for 5 minutes in somewhere.

Since our latency SLO is 60ms (p99), it is increasing the error rate of the system. I want to understand actually why it takes more than configured timeout to throw that exception and where is this the time spent.

Can you help me understand the possible causes of the issue I explained?

Would that be the eventloop, the exception is queued somehow (I don't know the internals of netty)? Or is the eventloop not handling the events immediately, just has a schedule like 5ms and checks the request timed out instead?

Or is it the time taken for the tcp connection added into the timeout which makes 55.3 (5.3ms for connection) (this would be interesting since the mock server is running locally) ?

I have verified the timeout configuration, it is valid. I have tried separating the event loop for the webclients, it didn't change the behaviour.

Comment: First of all, when using multiple async tasks, you might want to use `awaitAll(task1, task2, etc.)` instead of waiting each task in line. awaitAll guarantee failure as soon as possible, whereas you current approach raise error only when the coroutine arrive on the line `taskX.await()`. So, currently, if task 3 fails early, you won't known it  until after having fetched response from task1 and task2.